# Accessing my annotation in a mutable array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, nsmutablearray

In my application I added a few annotations. I have a AnnotationController with a shared instance so I can access my annotations in al my classes. I push the added annotations in a mutable array.

But, I want to add my annotationtitle's to a tableView so I want to load my array again and access my parameters I gave with 'initWithTitle'.

Something like this:

```
[AnnotationController sharedInstance].annotations[1].title ?
```

**The code**

```
NSArray *init = @[
    [[Annotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"America has a new President !" :@"Washington DC" :l1], // call method to add an annotation with these parameters
    [[Annotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Revolutionary app by Belgium student" :@"Antwerp" :l2],
    [[Annotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"The new Arabic revolution" :@"Egypt, Tahir square" :l3],
    [[Annotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"World Championchip football" :@"Rio de Janeiro" :l4],
];

[AnnotationController sharedInstance].annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:init]; // add the above array to a mutablearray se we can add objects and edit them
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to access your title of any specific annotation

```
[[[AnnotationController sharedInstance].annotations objectAtIndex:0] title]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all of the title's from the objects in the array you could use KVC

```
NSArray *annotations = [[AnnotationController sharedInstance] annotations];

NSArray *title = [annotations valueForKey:@"title"];
```

Taken from the docs for [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ)

> **valueForKey:**
>   Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.